# Form inheritance in C# Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't inherit two forms, here is the code for the parent form:

```
public partial class HelpForm : Form
{
    public HelpForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MinimizeBox = false;
        MaximizeBox = false;
        ControlBox = false;
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;

        AcceptButton = b_Ok;
        b_Ok.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        CancelButton = b_Cancel;
        b_Cancel.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the child form:

```
public partial class HelpForm_TwoTextBox : HelpForm
{
    public HelpForm_TwoTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The following error appears in the form constructor:

> It is impossible to show the constructor for this file, since it is impossible to construct any of the classes included in it. The designer has tested the following classes in this file: It is not possible to display a constructor for this file because none of the classes contained in it can be constructed. The designer checked the following classes in this file:
> HelpForm_TwoTextBox
> Unable to load base class 'BZMP.HelpForm'. Check that there is a link to the assembly and all projects are created.

I tried deleting files with the `.Design.cs` extension and rebuilding the project, tried re-creating the forms, nothing worked

Comment: The XXX.designer.cs files are needed. If you deleted them your code is broken.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to reuse some part of the UI you are probably better of putting any shared stuff in a custom control that is used by two independent forms. And in general you should try to use composition rather than inheritance if you want to reuse code.

Comment: I agree JonasH: inheriting from Forms is rarely a good idea. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance